# Is it possible to implement correct material design shadowing for an HTML element that's over two items with different heights?

Tags: html, css, material-design

In HTML, if you have an element that's floating over two other elements and all 3 have different depths, is it possible to create the appropriate [material-design](https://material.google.com/) shadowing for the upper element? I would think the shadow over the higher element would need to be different than the one over the lower element, right?

Basically, the question is: how should the blue square's box shadow look, and how would you do that in html/css(/javascript?)?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean depths, not heights?

Comment: You need to add more details, an example of what you are asking about would be very helpful

Comment: @Miro Yeah, I guess I mean depths. Changed that word (dunno what to do about the words "higher" and "lower" tho).

Comment: I can't help you without any code or specifics but this may be helpful: https://material.google.com/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows

Comment: @JacobGray Added a picture that should clarify things

Comment: @BT what exactly are you asking? How to create a shadow in CSS?

Comment: @JacobGray Are you familiar with material design? It uses shadows to create the feeling of depth. Since css box-shadows are only 2D aware and material design relies on a 3D conceptualization, my question is what is the appropriate way to do material design in HTML in this example where one element (blue) is over two other elements (red and green) that have different depths.

Comment: @BT I'm familiar with material. I would simply set the shadow with CSS box-shadow, like this https://jsfiddle.net/3r8oo1p8/

Answer (score 2):

CSS Shadows work completely different to material design shadows. In material design, shadows depend on the components' z coordinate (depth) so the shadows look very realistic. At the other hand, CSS shadows are defined by their x/y offset, blur and color, but not by their depth. They are not influenced by the components they are dropped on.

There might be tricks to achieve realistc shadows like in material design in some cases, but there's no solution that works everywhere.